# Can question about why a film is critically praised or not?

Tags: support, scope

For example, a film doesn't make sense and get high critical point but low user point on rottentomatoes, can I ask why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

This is basically asking for opinions and those are off-topic for Movies & TV.

> You should only ask **practical, answerable** questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> [Asking](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85677/46980) of a question that was closed for asking why a movie was well-liked by critics. It did get answered, but the answer literally just copy-pasted the "Critical reception" section of the film's Wikipedia page, so the question also shows a lack of research effort IMO.

Comment: Question updated, consier answer it again?

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change a question once it has been asked and answered. Ask a new question and refer back to this one.