# Can question about why a film is critically praised or not be asked? - More specific question

Tags: support, scope

This is the more specific version of  [Can question about why a film is critically praised or not?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/can-question-about-why-a-film-is-critically-praised-or-not/)

Although critical point is opinon from the critic, but:

(1) The question is not asking for answerer's personal opinion

(2) There could be common opinions from critics to give it a high point, then such opinion is not that "opinion based".

(3) The question is asking about is there any professional point of view that make the film critically praised which common audience are not familiar with and to learn such point of view and to think in a professional way. This make such question valuable.

Then can there be a specific rule for such questions and make it on-topic? Like require the answer to explain what is the main common reason for it to be praised by critcs which are omitted by the common audience?

In fact such answers are based on the fact which is composed of the opinions of the critics. There are so many critics for a film and each are so long that you don't have the time to read then to check out why so you ask this question.

Since each such film can produce one such question, it can be considered that such question can only be asked as community and published with a templated tool.

Answer (score 4):

## NO

> Like require the answer to explain what is the main common reason for it to be praised by critics which are omitted by the common audience?
>
> In fact such answers are based on the fact which is composed of the opinions of the critics. **There are so many critics for a film and each are so long that you don't have the time to read then to check out why so you ask this question.**

What makes you think anyone else has the time? All you are asking us to do is *summarise* the reviews down to a singe review for you to read.

**That's not something Movies & TV is intended for.**

We expect YOU to do significant research before posing a question and, in this case, if you did you wouldn't need to ask it.

Comment: "All you are asking us to do is summarise the reviews down to a singe review for you to read" That's not right - the intention is to let the insiders to give such common fact direcly - if you know any. "significant research" - read all the critics? If so, then SE is not needed at all, since any question can be answered  by yourself if you learn all human knowledge by yourself. An important type of question is you don't have time to learn all human knowledge but some insider can tell you the key information directly.